# How do I write a SQL JOIN query to read all programmes belonging to a department of a faculty?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a model of my tables as shown below:

1 faculty has many degree programmes

1 faculty has many departments

1 department belongs to 1 faculty

1 degree programme belongs to 1 faculty

1 department has many degree programmes

1 degree programme belongs to 1 department

[image: tables model diagram]

I want to fetch all degree programmes that belong to a certain faculty for example in the FST faculty and in a certain department for example department I4. I want to go through the following tables:

**degree programmes -> faculties -> departments**

The FST faculty has a total of 189 programmes and 9 departments.

If I run the below query I get a total of 1701 records. Which is (189 * 9). I get the same programmes fetched for each department.

```
SELECT 
degree_programmes.facul_fac_code,
degree_programmes.degree_name, 
faculties.faculty_name,
departments.dept_code,
departments.dept_name
FROM degree_programmes 
JOIN faculties ON degree_programmes.facul_fac_code = faculties.fac_code
JOIN departments ON faculties.fac_code=departments.fac_code
WHERE degree_programmes.facul_fac_code = 'FST';
```

If I run another query that I am using in my code shown below, I get the same number of programmes (189) irregardless of what department code I use in the query. I know for a fact that the departments in my database have different number of programmes that total to the number of programmes in their faculty.

```
SELECT 
degree_programmes.facul_fac_code,
degree_programmes.degree_name, 
faculties.faculty_name,
departments.dept_code,
departments.dept_name
FROM degree_programmes 
JOIN faculties ON degree_programmes.facul_fac_code = faculties.fac_code
JOIN departments ON faculties.fac_code=departments.fac_code
WHERE degree_programmes.facul_fac_code = 'FST'
AND departments.dept_code='I4';
```

How do fix the query above?

Comment: Your data model and your description of it are inconsistent. The model you have shown says that a degree program is associated to a single faculty but there is no restriction of a degree program to a department. If your description is correct then the model needs to change to link degree program to department (and remove the faculty>degree program link) and then there will be an implicit restriction of degree program to faculty

Comment: @NickW I noticed that. I have no control over the database and so I thought there was another way apart from introducing a relationship between the degree programmes and the departments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your schema, there is no relationship between `degree_programmes` and `departments`.

The first join between the faculty and the degree program is fine, and will give you all the degree programs by faculty (189), however, when you add the second join, you are joining each departments (9) in the faculty to the each of the degree_programs (189), which will then as you have noted give you 189 * 9 records.

In order to be able to produce the results you are looking for, you need to create an association between a department and a degree progam, and add that relationship as a condition in your join

```
SELECT 
   degree_programmes.facul_fac_code,
   degree_programmes.degree_name, 
   faculties.faculty_name,
   departments.dept_code,
   departments.dept_name
FROM 
   degree_programmes 
JOIN 
   faculties ON 
   degree_programmes.facul_fac_code = faculties.fac_code
JOIN 
   departments ON 
   faculties.fac_code=departments.fac_code AND
   <<<degree_programmes.dept_code = departments.dept_code>>>
WHERE 
   degree_programmes.facul_fac_code = 'FST'
   AND departments.dept_code='I4';
```

Comment: I had this solution in mind. However I was looking for another way to solve this without introducing another relationship between the degree programmes and departments. I have no control over the database.